# how to disable all dates except current date in java

Tags: java, datepicker

i am using datepicker for my java project. i don't want user to choose previous date and after date and only able to select current/today date only. can someone please give me suggestion.
Thanks in Advance
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihmdwaktqkm2isx/DatePicker.java?dl=0
please click the dropbox link for datepicker.java

Comment: why use a datePicker if the user can not pick a date?

Comment: You can use the system date, instead of giving it to choose by user

Comment: oops i just want to make user able to choose current date and future date

Comment: you say that you dont want the user to select past or future date! What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Date of the System, one way would be this:

For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
String time = sdf.format(new Date());
return time;
```

Will return the year, the month, the days, the hours, the minutes and the seconds.

This on the other Hand:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String time = sdf.format(new Date());
return time;
```

Will return only the year, the month and the day.
You can compare these values to what the user typed.
By splitting everything you can get everything itself:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String time = sdf.format(new Date());
split = time.split("/");
String year = split[0];
String month = split[1];
String day = split[2];
```

I hope this is what you wanted.